# preg_match for information in parentheses

Tags: php, preg-match

(ACCTG) Accounting

The text above I trying to get the information in the parentheses how would I do that in php this is what I have so far.

```
$regex = '#\((([^()]+|(?R))*)\)#';
if (preg_match_all($regex, $string ,$matches)) {
    echo implode(' ', $matches[1]);
} else {
    //no parenthesis
    echo $string;
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem / the question? What doesn't work? Is there an error?

Comment: @nikic I got it to work now nevermind weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do converting special characters to hex for easy use in my regex's

```
<?
$input = 'abc ("an example")';
if(preg_match("/\x28([^\x29]+)\x29/", $input, $matched)) { 
     //...         
    print_r($matched); 
} else { 
   //do something.. 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this be sufficient:

```
\(([^\)]*)\).*
```

Comment: Not if the parentheses can be nested.  (For example, something like this (with parentheses inside parentheses) would break with your expression.)

Comment: Exactly, but the problem given by the OP looked more like codes for departments inside the parenthesis. The next question would be, how to handle mismatched parenthesis. Like in `(AS(AS) Something` or `(DB))E) Deparment DBE`